# How to add views/layers dynamically in a horizontal collectionView by indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im making a timeline of sorts with a horizontal collectionView where for each block of time (a month), I have a cell with UIViews for each day with different colors. Some months have 30 views added, some 31, some 28. I am having trouble adding views dynamically to each cell such that they are not duplicated or added to the wrong cell.

To that end, I have created a simplified version of this timeline where each month only has 1 layer/view added to it dynamically - I will then try and tackle adding variable amounts of views/layers.

I made this project as the simplest possible example of what I'm talking about:

https://github.com/AlexMarshall12/testTimeline-iOS

Here is the code in ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var filledCells: [Int] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.filledCells = [1,28]
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 28
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        print(indexPath.item)
        cell.myLabel.text = String(indexPath.item)
        if filledCells.contains(indexPath.item) {
            let tickLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            tickLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.layer.bounds.width, height: cell.layer.bounds.height), cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
            tickLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.13, blue:0.25, alpha:0.5).cgColor
            cell.layer.addSublayer(tickLayer)
        } else {

        //updated 

            let tickLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            tickLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.layer.bounds.width, height: cell.layer.bounds.height), cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
            tickLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.1, green:0.13, blue:0.98, alpha:0.5).cgColor
            cell.layer.addSublayer(tickLayer)
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

The idea is that for each indexPath item (each cell?) it looks to see if that is contained in the self.filledCells array: 1 or 28 which happen to be the outer edges as there are 28 cells returned for numberOfItemsInSection and 1 section. So what I wanted to happen was for every cell to be light blue except for the 1rst and 28th - light red.

However, as you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVoGg.jpg. There are multiple shades of blue and red and purple as cells are filled multiple times as I scroll back and forth, certainly ones other than 1 and 28.

I think there are two issues.

1. Somehow indexPath.item is returning 1 or 28 even when I'm not scrolled to the very edge cells. Why is this?
2. When I revisit cells that are already rendered, it re-renders them. I'm not sure why this is. I was wondering if overriding prepareForReuse() could help but I've heard this is often a bad idea so Im not sure if its what I'm looking for.

Any advice on achieving this?

Comment: Can you update GitHub project? It doesn't have anything inside

Answer (score 3):

You're overlooking the fact that cells are reused.  When you change a cell fillColor, and it gets scrolled off, the cell that gets scrolled on reuses that cell, and you've just set its fill color to red, and you didn't turn it off.  Set the fillColor explicitly for each cell, whether it's red, white or clear color, don't set it for just the selected cells.

Comment: that does help but it seems the red cells are still being overwritten each time I scroll back to them - basically another layer gets added. Additionally if you add two different layers depending on whether its in [1,28] like I have in the updated code it often draws both - purple. What do I do to prevent this?

Comment: Every time you get called in cellForItemAt, you have to set your cell up from scratch, and remove anything in the cell that may have been put in the last time. So if the cell should be colored, remove the old layer colors and add the new.  If the cell should not be colored, remove the old layer colors and restore the cell to its original state.

Answer (score 2):

Its always a bad idea to add a view or a layer every time in table view cells or collection view cells. As you are reusing cells, there is no need to create **tickLayer** again and again. Make tickLayer as a global variable, initialize it in awakeFromNib funciton in MyCollectionViewCell, then change its fill color in cellForRow function.

Comment: awakeFromNib for the cell itself? Is the variable part of the cell class? I need the view to be dynamic - to be able to create a variable number of them for the purposes of the timeline sorry I will clarify that in the question.

Comment: awakeFromNib is a method in UICollectionViewCell. You need to override it in your custom cell. Initialise tickLayer there and just change its colour in cellForItemAtIndexPath function.

Comment: Global var is not the correct way to work with layers. Note that layers are parts of views (cells) - each cell should have its own copy of layer, which will have its sublayers, while also keeping in mind that cells are reused. Having a global var for a layer will simply remove tickLayer from previously processed cell, and add it to the current one. This could lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Adding/removing views to a cell is not a good idea.
There are two ways to finish this:
① Create different cells by their subviews; 
② Create a generic cell and control the subview‘s display via hidden and layout, and update when you get this cell with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what @Owen Hartnett says about reusability of cells, I would like to point out that you are recreating layers each time! This is equivalent of creating subviews.

Every time you encounter a cell inside `cellForItemAt` function, you should also check existence of pre-added layers. Something like (not syntactically perfect Swift, but pseudocode):

```
let bLayerFound = false;
for (layer: CALayer in cell.layer.sublayers)
{
   if (layer.name.equals("mylayer"))
   {
     let shapeLayer = layer as! CAShapeLayer
     bLayerFound = true;
     //set layer properties based on your business logic, as you don't know what this cell is holding due to reuse
     shapeLayer.path = //path
     shapeLayer.fillColor = //color
   }
}

if (bLayerFound == false)
{
   //create layer here, again
   let tickLayer = CAShapeLayer()

   //set layer properties based on your business logic, as you don't know what this cell is holding due to reuse
   tickLayer.path = //path
   tickLayer.fillColor = //color
   tickLayer.name = "mylayer"
   cell.layer.addSublayer(tickLayer)     
}
```

Couple of other caveats:

- It is better always to add UI to `cell.contentView`, not `cell` itself.
- Once you get it running, consider moving this code off to your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. If there is no subclass, maybe a separate function, so as not to clutter `cellForItemAt` with nasty if-else logic.